# Is Jsoup's select(CSS_selector) function guaranteed to return nodes in document order?

Tags: jsoup

The API docs dont explicitly state this... looking for insight from someone who has used it before.

I have tried it with some examples, and it seems to work, but still unsure of the "guarantee". My application requires the document order to be maintained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been crawling thousands of websites with `Jsoup` and **YES** it does return nodes in document order :)